# Is it possible to refactor Objective-C++ code in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, refactoring, objective-c++

I am a game developer. I have developed a game using box2d which is in Final Phase. To structure the code when i attempt to make code refactoring i am receiving this error alert http://screencast.com/t/ir1nCvnx . But when i attempt to make code refactoring for another project which is not using .mm suffix means i can make it out. The thing i want to know is can we do code refactoring for the code using c++ concepts. If not what is other way to do code refactoring.

Comment: As I know It is not possible to refactor the c++ code by Xcode. It only offers refactoring for obj-c code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought because Xcode depended on the clang front end for all of its
>   code coverage features, that it would eventually be able to refactor
>   C++. As I understood it, it didn't refactor C++ in the past because
>   clang's C++ support was still insufficient.
>
> But clang is a very good C++ compiler now. Yet Xcode still balks at
>   even renaming symbols (the only refactoring I've ever needed).

So, till now, you can not refactor your C++ code and hope you will get it with new release of clang / LLVM / XCode.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. So the only way is to do it manually for now :-(

Comment: I think so, as I did not find any such for now.